# Why is there more space after the brackets of `\textelp{}' than before?

Tags: spacing, csquotes, ellipsis

I've noticed something about `csquotes`'s `\textelp` about which no-one seems to have asked here before. With the minimal LaTeX input

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \textelp{} sit amet
\end{document}
```

I get this output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/NixOS.org) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.2.2)  13 FEB 2021 12:20
entering extended mode
[...]
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01>
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
```

> [image: pdfLaTeX output]

There is more space to the right of the bracketed ellipsis than to the left (specifically, 17 pixels to the right and 13 to the left (i.e., ~31% more space on the right), in the zoomed-in image above).

In this real-world, un-zoomed example of this asymmetry, there are 7 pixels to the right of the bracketed ellipsis and 5 to the left (i.e., 40% more space on the right), making the asymmetry more visible:

> [image: pdfLaTeX output]

I don't see this mentioned in the documentation of `\textelp` in `csquotes.pdf`. Is this asymmetry the intended behavior? If so, why? If not, why would it happen, and (more importantly to me) is it feasible for `csquotes` to fix, or easy for me to patch over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard ellipsis leaves the space factor of the period, which is correct in case the ellipsis ends a sentence and is irrelevant if something else follows.

The command `\textelp`, to the contrary, should never end a sentence, so `\@` should be added.

In the example below, the extra space after a sentence ending period is enlarged to better show what happens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\xspaceskip=20pt % to make the spacing more evident

% this is the default definition
% \newcommand{\mktextelp}{[\textellipsis\unkern]}

Lorem ipsum \textelp{} sit amet

% the fix
\renewcommand{\mktextelp}{[\textellipsis\unkern]\@}

Lorem ipsum \textelp{} sit amet

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also `\mktextelpins` should be redefined in the same way:

```
\renewcommand{\mktextelpins}[1]{[\textellipsis\unkern\@] [#1]}
```

Comment: See issue report at https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/issues/34